# bootstrap Google Map not centering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center a Google Map API using bootstrap, but it is not working.
Please see the image regarding the issue.
The text is centering, but not the map.
![Map Issue Picture]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jUnE.jpg

I have tried every which way of putting 'text-center' in surrounding elements, and putting the map  in 'col-md-6' but nothing is working.
I am sure I am missing something silly.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">My Map</h1>
    <div class="text-center" id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The div #map needed the Bootstrap class:

```
class = "mx-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>My Map</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="map">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d14475.259566651797!2d91.88062475!3d24.90429495!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbd!4v1563361490340!5m2!1sen!2sbd" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Wrap your `<h1>` and `<div>` tag within `.row` > `.col`

1. Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your
   site’s contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or
   .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device
   sizes.
2. Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
   (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This
   padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This
   way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the
   left side.
3. In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
   columns may be immediate children of rows.

For reference go through https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ this link